# SD Card Reader not Appearing

Tags: sd-card

I have a Lenovo Y50 laptop, with a built in Card reader.

It was working one day, R/W normally, and then nothing.

- Nothing shows in Disk Management, nor Device Manager, even when showing hidden devices
- There's no action/sound whatsoever when I insert a SD card.
- I have tried with 3 separate SD cards, one straight out of the packagine.

I am not sure what to do, it seems like there is no driver and no device appears.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to try when something like this happens is to check your drivers. Go to the Lenovo support site and download the latest drivers, not just for the card reader, but also for chipset.

Second, install any Windows updates (or, if updates were installed recently, try removing some of them).

If neither of these steps work, open the Command window and run `sfc /scannow` on your computer. This will check your Windows installation for any missing or corrupt files.

Comment: There was some updates, actually, come to think of it.

Comment: Glad that worked for you. It's possible the updates caused issues with already old drivers. Just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

Although this wont solve your problem, i would recommend filtering out possible causes by creating a Bootable linux usb and test it in linux

If it doesnt work you can assume it is hardware related, highly improbable

If it does, i would assume the problem lies with either the drivers and or the system having changed,

I recommend reinstalling the relevant drivers, should do the trick.